# Coverage report for 'pytest' different when run in code vs CLI

Tags: python, pytest

When I use the `pytest` CLI to run some tests against my small module, the coverage report that is output is complete and shows 100% coverage.

However, when I run the tests in code using the `pytest` module, the coverage report is incomplete (missing the ****init**.py** file) and shows some lines as missing. But this cannot be the case, as all of the tests pass.

Looking at the file **colours.py**, the lines listed as missing are all of the `import` statements, `class` definitions, class parameters, method definitions and decorators.

Note that I have compared the verbose output for both runs, and other than the difference in coverage and the odd millisecond of execution time, they are identical.

What could be causing this inconsistent behaviour?

#### Tests run via the CLI

```
pytest ./az/tests/unit --cov src --cov-report term-missing
```

```
================================ test session starts ================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.3.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/dgard/repos/management-groups/az/tests
configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: cov-4.1.0, dependency-0.5.1
collected 31 items                                                                  

az/tests/unit/colours_test.py ...............................                 [100%]

31 assertions pased.

---------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.10.6-final-0 -----------
Name                 Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
--------------------------------------------------
az/src/__init__.py       1      0   100%
az/src/colours.py       35      0   100%
--------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                   36      0   100%


================================ 31 passed in 0.10s =================================
```

## Tests run via code

```py
import pytest

pytest_args = ['./az/tests/unit', '--cov', 'src', '--cov-report', 'term-missing']
pytest.main(pytest_args)
```

```
================================ test session starts ================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.3.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/dgard/repos/management-groups/az/tests
configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: cov-4.1.0, dependency-0.5.1
collected 31 items                                                                  

az/tests/unit/colours_test.py ...............................                 [100%]

31 assertions pased.

---------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.10.6-final-0 -----------
Name                Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------------------
az/src/colours.py      35     15    57%   1-18, 42-43
-------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                  35     15    57%


================================ 31 passed in 0.09s =================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here seems to be that the script being tested has already been imported by the module that was running `pytest.main()` in code.

To get around the issue, I am reimporting the script in the tests.

```py
import colours
import importlib


importlib.reload(assets.colours)
```